# BigQuery loading Parquet, 30x space in BQ

Tags: google-bigquery, parquet

A BigQuery noob here.

I have a pretty simple but large table coming from clickhouse and stored in a parquet file to be loaded into BQ.

Size: 50GB in parquet, About 10B rows

Schema:
key:STRING(it was a UUID),type:STRING(cardinality of 4, e.g. CategoryA,CategoryB,CategoryC),value:FLOAT

Size in BigQuery: ~1.5TB

This is about a 30x increase.

Running a `SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE type=CategoryA` shows an expected billing of 500GB, which seems a rather large number given such a low cardinality.

It feels there are two paths:

- making the query more efficient (how?)
- or even better, making BQ understand the data more and avoid a 30x increase explosion.

Clustering and partitioning could come handy in specific instances of selection, however it seems that the 30x problem still remains, and the moment you start running the wrong query it will just explode in cost

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Parquet file is compressed format, so when loaded it will be decompressed.

1.5TB is not huge in BQ world.
Neither the 500GB. * the columns you touch in the `where` statement are scanned as well.

What you need to do is that you reframe into smaller data sets.

Leverage partitioning and clustering as well.
Never use * in select.

Use materialized views for specific use cases, and turn on BI Engine for optimized queries see a [guide](https://medium.com/p/9e2634c84a82) here.

Comment: Thanks Pentium10. I recognize it is not huge, but seems very inefficient as well when it comes to pricing given the space could be so much smaller

Comment: There is nothing on the cloud market that is so cheap as BigQuery for large data. Storage is considered cheap. If your query touchas data volume that is bigger than RAM size of decent VM, the affordable good solution is data lake.